# Updating a class after changing its Interface

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, shortcut

Say I add a function to an outstanding Interface.
In Visual Studio, within a class which implements it I can right click the Interface declaration and re-implement it. This will update the code to reflect the changes made. Is there anyway to do the same thing in eclipse?
It'd be nice if there was.
I've searched the net, alas no joy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the cursor on the name of the class and press `CTRL+1` to activate the quick-fix. That should offer the option of adding the new method.

UPDATE: BTW, here's a [really handy list of Eclipse keyboard shortcuts](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-shortcut-key). If you're on Mac, you can *usually* substitute `⌘` for `CTRL`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the source menu. Select Source > Override/Implement methods.